# Avoid Javascript "The local variable may not have been initialized" warning in backbone.js Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, initialization

Eclipse says that EventCategories(active) is a potential local variable that hasn't been initialized. I don't see how this how to avoid this. Any help? I'm also a Backbone.js newb, so I'm not sure that I'm actually doing this right (even though it works).

```
define([ "modules/config/model/event-category" ], function(EventCategory) {
    var EventCategories = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : EventCategory,
        url : restEndpoint + "/config/category",
        getActive : function() {
            var active = this.filter(function(eventCategory){
                return eventCategory.get("active") === true;
            });
            return new EventCategories(active);
        }
    });
    return EventCategories;
});
```

Comment: Are you sure it is complaining about `active` and not `restEndpoint`?

Comment: It is actually complaining about EventCategories -- which is the Collection object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could use [`this.constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) as a backdoor way to getting at `EventCategories`:

> **Object.prototype.constructor**
>
> Returns a reference to the `Object` function that created the instance's prototype. Note that the value of this property is a reference to the function itself, not a string containing the function's name.

So if `this` is an `EventCategories` instance then `this.constructor === EventCategories`. In your case, you could say:

```
return new this.constructor(active);
```